# python multiline regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

How do I extract all the characters (including newline characters) until the first occurrence of the giver sequence of words? For example with the following input:

input text:

```
"shantaram is an amazing novel.
It is one of the best novels i have read.
the novel is written by gregory david roberts.
He is an australian"
```

And the sequence `the` 
I want to extract text from `shantaram` to first occurrence of `the` which is in the second line.

The output must be-

```
shantaram is an amazing novel.
It is one of the
```

I have been trying all morning. I can write the expression to extract all characters until it encounters a specific character but here if I use an expression like:

```
re.search("shantaram[\s\S]*the", string)
```

It doesn't match across newline.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results"

Comment: i have been trying from morning. I can write the expression to extract all characters until it encounters a specific character. But here if i use an expression like-
re.search("shantaram[\s\S]*the", string)
it doesnt work as the is a part of [\s\S] and the extraction is not happening

Answer (score 28):

You want to use the `DOTALL` option to match across newlines. From [doc.python.org](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL):

> re.DOTALL
>
> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

Demo:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s="""shantaram is an amazing novel.
It is one of the best novels i have read.
the novel is written by gregory david roberts.
He is an australian"""

In [3]: print re.findall('^.*?the',s,re.DOTALL)[0]
shantaram is an amazing novel.
It is one of the
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this regex,

```
re.search("shantaram[\s\S]*?the", string)
```

instead of

```
re.search("shantaram[\s\S]*the", string)
```

The only difference is '?'. By using '?'(e.g. *?, +?), you can prevent longest matching.

Answer (score 1):

A solution not using regex:

```
from itertools import takewhile
def upto(a_string, stop):
    return " ".join(takewhile(lambda x: x != stop and x != "\n".format(stop), a_string))
```